# Changing style on <body> element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to React so this may be simple but I cannot for the life of me find anything in the docs because the  element is outside the ReactDOM.

I am using material-ui for the user interface and that provides two themes: `lightBaseTheme` (the default) and `darkBaseTheme` with darker colors. Sort of day and night modes. The problem is that neither apply any styling to the `<body>` so the page background does not follow the theme. The dark theme uses white text which does not show on the default white background.

I suspect that I need to find a programmatic solution and set the  background color based on the currently loaded theme.

But how? I have tried putting code in the componentDidUpdate method of the top level component but that seems to always return the light theme. In any case I am not sure it is good practice to directly write to the DOM even though the `body` element is outside anything that is going to be affected by React.

```
export default class app extends React.Component {

    componentDidUpdate () {
        const muiTheme = getMuiTheme();
        const canvasColor = muiTheme.palette.canvasColor;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = canvasColor;
    }

    render () {
        const muiTheme = getMuiTheme();
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
                <span>Rest of the app goes here</span>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
};
```

The call to getMuiTheme in componentDidUpdate always returns lightBaseTheme even after it has been set in the render call.

I should perhaps add that the ultimate intention is to be able to change the theme on-the-fly so directly styling the `<body` element is not an option.

Comment: Would styling some `div` wrapping the whole app, instead of `body` serve your needs? That way you could use standard `style` props.

Comment: @MichałWerner Hi, I think this would not be ideal because sometimes react do write html elements directly on the body, outside of the `#root` Eg. popovers, dialogs...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If possible, the best solution would be to use a top level `div` inside your React app in addition to the style props to solve your issue.

However, what you have now won't work because `componentDidUpdate()` doesn't get called on initialization, and you don't seem to be having anything update it with props/state after loading.

> **componentDidUpdate()** is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render. ([React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate))

Instead, use `componentDidMount()`, which is called as soon as the component mounts to your DOM.

> **componentDidMount()** is invoked immediately after a component is mounted. Initialization that requires DOM nodes should go here. If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request. Setting state in this method will trigger a re-rendering. ([React Docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount))

[Here's a good write up on the component lifecycle](http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/).

Comment: A top level DIV within the React App was my first approach but I could not get it to render over the whole page. However this has thrown up another issue which may be better as a different question.

Comment: I chose componentDidUpdate bacause I needed it to update if the theme was changed. Even with this limitation getMuiTheme was returning the light theme even if the dark theme was being used.

Comment: A top level DIV was the way I finally solved it. I had the min-height set on the html element and changing that to height: 100% fills the page. Don't know it that will cause problems later though if it overflows the page. But for now I can style the background which is what I wanted.

Comment: This might not work in all cases, because React MUI may append stuff directly on the body (like popovers, select, dialogs...) and those would not be targetted by some of your div style

Answer (score 0):

You can use document.body.className. Check out [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp). And componentDidMount is a better place to put it.

Comment: I am not sure that this would enable me to change the style on the fly. If that wasn't a requirement this seems an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture the theme during a "ref" callback and assign it to a variable. Then pick that variable up in componentDidMount() (only called once, whereas componentDidUpdate() is called anytime props and state are changed):

```
export default class app extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        const canvasColor = this.theme.palette.canvasColor;
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = canvasColor;
    }

    render () {
        const muiTheme = getMuiTheme();
        return (
            <MuiThemeProvider ref={ref => (this.theme = ref.props.muiTheme)} muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>
                <span>Rest of the app goes here</span>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        );
    }
};
```