# ReactJS vs HTML - different renderings

Tags: reactjs

This is derived from my question here: [Changing style on <body> element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40746413/changing-style-on-body-element) where the suggestion was to style a top level DIV. Having tried that I find that I get a different output using React compared to direct HTML. I am at a loss to understand why.

Consider a very simple react app consisting of a basic index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html { min-height: 100%; }
            body { height: 100%; background-color: blue; margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='root'></div>
        <script src="https://fb . me / react-15.0.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fb . me / react-dom-15.0.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and a corresponding main.js file

```
var TestDiv = React.createClass({
    render: function () {
        const style = {
            divStyle: {
                height: "100%",
                background: "red"
            }
        }
        return (
            <div style={style.divStyle}>
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<TestDiv/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Rendering this produces a blue screen with a red bar at the top with the text on. With the DIV set to a height of 100% I had expected the red background to fill the viewport.

Now, take the output from that React app (as given by Chrome Inspector) and create a simple html file from it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html { min-height: 100%; }
            body { height: 100%; background-color: blue; margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root">
            <div data-reactroot="" style="height: 100%; background: red;">
                <h1>Hello World</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="https://fb . me/react-15.0.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://fb . me/react-dom-15.0.1.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
        <script src="main.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The code is essentially the same but this renders with the whole viewport in red and no blue at all.

Why?

Comment: You're missing a doctype tag in plain html version, hence the difference in rendering

Comment: Doh! Rookie error. Many thanks. Working now